# Laptop keyboard juice spill, certain keys don't work with brand new keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard, motherboard, asus-laptop, water-damage

Some juice was spilled on my laptop keyboard [N61 JV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4mWd.jpg). Once it dried out, a bunch of keys stopped working. After replacing it with a brand new, some keys still don't work around a particular region, namely: 9, o, l, ., \ and the down arrow. The new keyboard is definitely flawless as it has been tested in another compatible laptop. Is the motherboard partly damaged or is there a more specific replacable component that could be faulty?

Another potentially helpful observation is that a particular piece of the board seems to be fried or somewhat different as the other similar group of chips on the circuit

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely issue is damage to the board connector/cable.

1. A build-up of conductive fruit-juice across traces or the edge connector could cause an issue. Use a magnifier and alcohol-soaked swab to clean what you can find, and dry *thoroughly*.
2. Damage to the board connector/cable, such as a broken trace, could also be an issue. That damage could be caused by electrolytic corrosion from the juice and power supply. If a trace is damaged, it will need to be bridged with car defroster silver repair paint or solder. You may need a continuity detector to find a break.